# go fiber imolement google wire

Tags: go, go-fiber

I want to implement depedency injection with google wire in my fiber project
this my wire.go

```
//go:build wireinject
// +build wireinject
    
    package main
    
    import (
        "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
        "github.com/google/wire"
        "github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/internal/database"
        "github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/internal/handlers"
        "github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/internal/repositories"
        "github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/internal/routes"
        "github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/internal/usecases"
    )
    
    func InitializeApp() (*fiber.App, error) {
        wire.Build(
            database.ConnectDB,
            repositories.NewAgentRepositoryImpl,
            usecases.NewAgentUsecaseImpl,
            handlers.NewAgentHandlerImpl,
            fiber.New,
            routes.SetupRoutes,
        )
        return nil, nil
    }
```

and if I run `wire` I get an error :

```
jr_pikong@jrpikong:~/Projects/code/github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/cmd/server$ wire
wire: /home/jr_pikong/Projects/code/github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/cmd/server/wire_en.go:16:1: inject InitializeApp: no provider found for []github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.Config
        needed by *github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.App in provider "New" (/home/jr_pikong/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2@v2.52.2/app.go:499:6)
wire: github.com/jrpikong/h2h-gofiber/cmd/server: generate failed
wire: at least one generate failure
```